# Swift get video duration from firebase storage

Tags: swift, firebase, video-streaming, avurlasset

I'm working on an app that's similar to YouTube functionalities. Now I need to display a list of videos (already stored in Firebase) in a collectionView and I need to get the duration of each video. I'm considering to

1. add a property `duration` to `struct Post` and just get it easily when loading the posts.
2. create an object of `AVURLAsset` from the url of the video and get the duration from `asset.duration`. However, my intuition tells me this second option is not that good an idea.

I'm now in the very early stage of my career as an iOS developer; I badly need a solution to this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would add the `duration` property (perhaps as a double in seconds) when uploading the video -- it would hardly take up any storage, and it is easy to fetch and parse.